# Adobe Flash CS5 where is the language selection menu

Tags: flash, user-interface, graphics, adobe

Where is the language selection menu in Flash CS5 I've been looking for it but lost.

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about CS5, but it should part of the installer. However, I vaguely remember Adobe release specific language discs.

Comment: During installation I got language selection menu but there wasn't Egnlish (

Comment: Then it's probably a language specific install disc.

Comment: I think so too I need to get language pack for English, Thanks